Digital Nomads Residence Cards, type of Permit for Estonia and Romania
I'm a citizen of Turkey and our military conscription can be delayed if the person holds a long term residence card in a 3rd country, this is the exact translation of the rule here

Turkish citizens residing in foreign countries recognized by the Republic of Turkey can have their military service postponed under the following conditions:
Those who have a residence permit, including a work permit, or a direct work permit, and are employed as workers, employers, professionals, or artisans.

I was able to confirm Spanish digital nomad visa does work, since on the Residence card itself (The TYPE OF PERMIT includes the word "Work")
My question is can I apply for the extension if I have a digital nomad for 12 months for the following countries:

Estonia
Croatia
Romania

TLDR, I need to find out what the Residence Card says for the "TYPE OF PERMIT" for these countries and if it mentions working.
